# Show that the rv $X = -X$

Tags: probability

Let $X\in N(0,1)$ and show that $X=-X$ (equal in distribution)

I assume that I need to use the distribution function for the standard normal probability density.
So we have: $\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{\frac{-t^2}{2}}dt$.

But if $\Phi(x)=\Phi(-x)$, on the integral, the $x$es will be on negative respectively positive line. They should not equal to each other?

Comment: I had some quite confusing typos in details in my answer initially.  (I hope) I've fixed them now.  If so, it proves the result.  Your question says $\Phi(x)=\Phi(-x)$.  That is incorrect.  Actually $\Phi(x) = 1-\Phi(-x)$.  But if $\varphi=\Phi\,'$, the $\varphi(x)=\varphi(-x)$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

Let (capital) $F$ be the cumulative distribution function and let (lower-case) $f$ be the density, for the random variable $X$.

We know $f$ is an even function, i.e. $f(x)=f(-x)$.

So
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\Pr(X\le x) & =F'(x)=f(x)=f(-x) = F'(-x) \\[10pt]
& = -(-F'(-x)) = -\frac{d}{dx}F(-x) \\[10pt]
& = -\frac{d}{dx} \Pr(X\le -x) \\[10pt]
& = -\frac{d}{dx} \Pr(-X\ge x) \\[10pt]
& = -\frac{d}{dx}\left( 1-\Pr(-X\le x) \right) \\[10pt]
& = \frac{d}{dx} \Pr(-X\le x).
\end{align}

So $\Pr(X\le x)=\Pr(-X\le x)+\text{constant}$.  The expression to the left of "$=$" and the expression before "${}+\text{constant}$" both approach the same limit as $x\to\infty$, so the constant must be $0$.

Thus we have
$$
\Pr(X\le x) = \Pr(-X\le x).
$$

Comment: Well, I don't know any other way to show this. I think you've shown explicitly enough..